runtime_version.h file not found when trying to run libfuzzer with libprotobuf-mutator
I have a file calc.cc
#include <cassert>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>
#include "ast.pb.h"
#include "src/libfuzzer/libfuzzer_macro.h"

int eval(const ast::Expr &E) {
    if (E.has_constant())
        return E.constant().val();
    if (E.has_unop()) {
        auto unopkind = E.unop().kind();
        int evaldarg = eval(E.unop().arg());
        if (unopkind == ast::UnaryOp::ABS) {
            return (evaldarg < 0) ? -evaldarg : evaldarg;
        }
        if (unopkind == ast::UnaryOp::SQRT) {
            return sqrt(evaldarg);
        }
        assert(false && "Unhandled case");
    }
    if (E.has_binop()) {
        auto binopkind = E.binop().kind();
        int evaldleft = eval(E.binop().left());
        int evaldright = eval(E.binop().right());
        switch (binopkind) {
            case ast::BinaryOp::PLUS:
                return evaldleft + evaldright;
            case ast::BinaryOp::MINUS:
                return evaldleft - evaldright;
            case ast::BinaryOp::MUL:
                return evaldleft * evaldright;
            case ast::BinaryOp::DIV:
                return evaldleft / evaldright;
            case ast::BinaryOp::MOD:
                return evaldleft % evaldright;
            default:
                assert(false && "Unhandled case");
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}

DEFINE_PROTO_FUZZER(const ast::Expr &E) {
    try {
        eval(E);
    } catch (...) {}
}

I also have a file ast.proto
syntax = "proto2";

package ast;

message Const {
  required int32 val = 1;
}

message BinaryOp {
  enum Binop {
    PLUS = 0;
    MINUS = 1;
    MUL = 2;
    DIV = 3;
    MOD = 4;
  }
  required Binop kind = 1;
  required Expr left = 2;
  required Expr right = 3;
}

message UnaryOp {
  enum UnOp {
    ABS = 1;
    SQRT = 2;
  }
  required UnOp kind = 1;
  required Expr arg = 2;
}

message Expr {
  oneof expr_oneof {
    Const constant = 1;
    BinaryOp binop = 2;
    UnaryOp unop = 3;
  }
}

I am trying to compile calc.cc and fuzz it using the libfuzzer and liprotobuf-mutator. I compiled the proto file using the command

protoc -I=$PWD --cpp_out=$PWD $PWD/ast.proto

I then used the following command to fuzz:

clang++ -o calc_fuzzer calc.cc ast.pb.cc -lprotobuf -lprotobuf-mutator
-lprotobuf-mutator-libfuzzer -I/usr/local/include -I. -fsanitize=address,fuzzer

Now I did install protoc and the version is libprotoc 27.0-dev. I build libprotobuf-mutator from source. When I checked the /usr/local/include directory there was a libprotobuf-mutator directory, so I guess the installation was successful. I build the protobuf from source using bazel. When I checked, /usr/include/google/protobuf exists, but there is no runtime_version.h header file in that directory. Also note that the directory /usr/local/include/google does not exist. I saw a post https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10976 which does have the same problem and the issue was solved by downgrading the protoc version. Which version of protoc is suitable with libprotobuf-mutator. Could anyone please provide any ways to resolve this? Thanks a lot for your time.
